# Get-AzureWebsiteLog -Tail not working

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to use the Azure PowerSheel command "Get-AzureWebsiteLog -Tail" as in the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/get-azurewebsitelog?view=azuresmps-4.0.0 but it is giving an error:

> No default subscription has been designated. Use
>   `Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName>` to set the
>   default subscription

When I try to execute the suggested command (Select-AzureSubscription -Default ) by replacing `<subscriptionName>` with my account name, which is "Free Trial", I get the following error:

> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> No default subscription has been designated. Use 
>   Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the
>   default subscription

We should use this command to select default subscription:

`Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN' -Default`

Comment: When I run the command you provided I get this error: Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name Free Trial doesn't exist.

Comment: Please add '' to test it

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using. Please see the command: Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'Free Trial' -Default

Comment: Please run get-azurermsubscription to get your subscription name

Comment: I got the following result: Name     : Free Trial - I also got the Id and the TenantId

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Select-azurermsubscription will work but after it works I still get the same error when I execute Get-AzureWebsiteLog -Tail. Is this kind of a mystery in Azure? I left this issue a month ago and I came back to it again to face exactly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

*Notes: This is a generic answer to your question's title, not your actual question, but it should be useful to others.*

---

If you're using 'Slot Deployment' you may run the log command and see nothing.

Each 'slot' represents a different app so you must ensure you specify the fully qualified name. If you don't know the full name run this command for a full list:

> Get-AzureWebsite

So if you're deploying to a 'Staging' slot then look for something like this:

> Name       : XXXfunctions-ui(Staging)
>   State      : Running
>   Host Names : {XXXfunctions-ui-staging.azurewebsites.net}

Then (with quotes) run the command:

> Get-AzureWebSiteLog -Name "XXXfunctions-ui(Staging)" -Tail